# Converting specific column values to header and header to column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv like this,

```
Market_id   Metric  New_Mar_19  New_Feb_19  tot_Mar_19  tot_Feb_19  
7528            1       9           7           6.5         8           
7528            2       6           3.2         2.2         3
```

I want to convert the above csv to like this below,

```
  Month         Nrx_count       Nrx_quantity    Trx_count       Trx_quantity

    Mar_19      9                   6               6.5             2.2
    Feb_19      7                   3.2             8               3
```

I have tried using pivot and pd.melt but I am not able to like above.

Comment: I am thinking about `Nrx` and `Trx`, what is logic for assign to output columns?

Comment: @jezrael, Basically my metric, market_id and other column will be having repeating values, its throwing error 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'
Could you help ?

Comment: @jezrael, Is it possible to do this whole transformation is SQL ?

Comment: I think is it possible, but it is something similar like pivot, what is really complicated in SQL.

Comment: @jezrael can u help on that ?

Comment: In SQL no, because I have only basic knowledge. But for `'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'` working for solution now, plese give me some time.

Comment: @jezrael, ya sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is convert columns without `_` to `MultiIndex`, then split column by `_` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Market_id','Metric'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack()
print (df1)
                         New  tot
Market_id Metric                 
7528      1      Feb_19  7.0  8.0
                 Mar_19  9.0  6.5
          2      Feb_19  3.2  3.0
                 Mar_19  6.0  2.2

#second level, here Metric is converted to columns
df1 = df1.unstack(1)
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'y'})
print (df1)
   Market_id       y  New_1  New_2  tot_1  tot_2
0       7528  Feb_19    7.0    3.2    8.0    3.0
1       7528  Mar_19    9.0    6.0    6.5    2.2
```

---

```
#first level, here Market_id is converted to columns
df1 = df1.unstack(0)
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'y'})
print (df1)
   Metric       y  New_7528  tot_7528
0       1  Feb_19       7.0       8.0
1       1  Mar_19       9.0       6.5
2       2  Feb_19       3.2       3.0
3       2  Mar_19       6.0       2.2
```

EDIT:

If get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates. Solution is same, only is necessary add aggregation - e.g. by `mean`, `sum`...

```
#change data for duplicates in column for Multiindex - Market_id, Metric
print (df)
   Market_id  Metric  New_Mar_19  New_Feb_19  tot_Mar_19  tot_Feb_19
0       7528       1           2         5.0         5.0           8
1       7528       1          10        20.0         2.5          16
2       7528       2           6         3.2         2.2           3  

df1 = df.set_index(['Market_id','Metric'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack()
print (df1)
                          New   tot
Market_id Metric                   
7528      1      Feb_19   5.0   8.0
                 Mar_19   2.0   5.0
                 Feb_19  20.0  16.0
                 Mar_19  10.0   2.5
          2      Feb_19   3.2   3.0
                 Mar_19   6.0   2.2
```

---

```
#number of levels passes to groupby - here 3 levels -> 0,1,2
print (df1.index.nlevels)
3

#grouping by all levels and aggregate mean, sum,max...
df1 = df1.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).mean().unstack(1)
print (df1)
                   New         tot     
Metric               1    2      1    2
Market_id                              
7528      Feb_19  12.5  3.2  12.00  3.0
          Mar_19   6.0  6.0   3.75  2.2
```

---

```
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'y'})
print (df1)
   Market_id       y  New_1  New_2  tot_1  tot_2
0       7528  Feb_19   12.5    3.2  12.00    3.0
1       7528  Mar_19    6.0    6.0   3.75    2.2
```

Comment: sorry I want the market_id column also in output
Could you also help me with that ?

Comment: Will this kind of approach works if i have few other columns like market_id ?

Comment: @venkat - Change `df1 = df.set_index(['Market_id','Metric'])` to `df1 = df.set_index(['Market_id','Metric', 'col without _', 'another col without_'])`

Comment: Basically my metric, market_id and other column will be having repeating values, its throwing error
Could you help ?

Comment: Can you help me in converting this python code to pyspark code

Comment: @venkat: it looks like you have a new question. If you have done sufficient research on the problem, then ask a new question. You can invite someone to take a look by providing the link to them, but tread carefully - if someone had the time to help you on this occasion, it does not mean they will always have the time to help you.

Comment: ("Convert this code for me" is also off-topic here).